# Papa.parse memory error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, memory

data.csv file size maybe 100M~300M

now, memory leak error happend.(IE / Chrome)

How can I solved...?

it's no problem if loading so long time

```
Papa.parse("/data.csv",{
    download: true,
    delimiter: ",", // auto-detect
    newline: "\n",  // auto-detect
    header: false,
    dynamicTyping: false,
    preview: 0,
    encoding: "",
    worker: true,
    comments: false,
    step: function(result, handle) {
        if (result.data[0][0]) {
            data.push(result.data[0]);
        }
    },
    complete: function() {
        parseGene(Date.now(), scaffold, data, 0, "", [], [], 0);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    skipEmptyLines: false,
    chunk: function(results) {
        rows.concat(rows, results.data);
    },
    fastMode: false
});
```